# Usage of extern & inline

Tags: c++, extern

In my C++ code, I have a definition like that;

```
class A {
    int i;
public:
    void setI(int temp) {
        i = temp;
    }
};

extern A* a;
```

After that I have a function which fills the variable of a with some stream obtained from arguments.

```
inline void Func() {
    ... // Stream definition with ifstream etc.
    int k;
    stream >> k;
    a->setI(k);    // Gives segmentation fault...
}
```

What can be the reason?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: `a` is a pointer. It's probably not been initialised. Where is `a` declared?

Comment: Pointer needs to point a valid memory location.

Comment: You should provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to let other people help you...

Comment: a is the same a with the extern A* a

Comment: @qwerty Again: How do you initialize that pointer? (I removed the irrelevant tags)

Comment: An `extern` declaration says that the definition is elsewhere. Where do you *define* `a`? Also, where do you assign to `a` a valid pointer to `A`?

Comment: The problem here has nothing to do with `extern` or `inline`. It's just an uninitialized (or possibly null) pointer.

Comment: The codes above are in my .h file. In cpp file I also declared "a" as "A* a".

Comment: How can I initialize this pointer according to my class?

Comment: @qwerty Well again (again): **How do you initialize that pointer in your `.cpp` file??**

Comment: I didn't initialize it. I just declared and fill it in Func()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `a = new A()` somewhere in your initilization code. A more better way would be to call `Func(A *a)` with an argument instead of using your "extern" statement.

Comment: you could explain OP what the `Func` should do by some example... don't hesitate to edit your answer to make it better